# Issue with find element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I am using **Selenium v3.8.0**, also I do the coding in **C#**.

Now I try to validate if **XPath** or the **webElement** exists on the site, though I don't success

Now I try to validate the text **Login**

then I want to alert it in console:

Here is my attempt:

```
 if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//h3[@translate='TITLE_LOGIN']"))) {
       Console.WriteLine("Element exists");         
 }
 else {                    
       Console.WriteLine("Element not displayed");            
 }

 private bool IsElementPresent(By by) {
       try
       {
           Driver.Instance.FindElement(by);
           return true;
       }
       catch (NoSuchElementException)
       {
           return false;
       }
 }
```

see picture below:
[image: Picture 1]

Link to URL: [Owasp Juiceshop](https://juice-shop.herokuapp.com/#/login)

Comment: I was able to find the Login element with document.evaluate("//h3[@translate='TITLE_LOGIN']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ) on the Firefox console. Could you display the errors/outputs of your C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool IsPresent= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div/section/h3")).Displayed;
if (IsPresent)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Element exists");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Element not displayed");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By using `Displayed` or (`isDisplayed()` method in Java) we may get `NoSuchElementException`

In order to avoid the exception, we may use the below code:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(<By locator>);

if(element.size()>0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Element exists");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Element not displayed");
}
```